# Vues.js unit test w Karma-Mocha-HeadlessChrome , why message INFO about Vue Devtools?

Tags: vue.js, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless

running my unit tests, I am always getting this info messsage even if I already added the Devtools extension in my Chrome browser ?

```
yves$ npm run unit
> shopping-list@1.0.0 unit /Users/yves/Developments//shopping-list
> cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run

[karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
launcher]: Launching browser ChromeHeadless with unlimited concurrency
[launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6)]: Connected on socket s3ED3TVFNjuvVojoAAAA with id 22013100

INFO LOG: 'Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools'
```

I found a way to get rid of it , inserting in my actions.spec.js the following piece of code :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
const isHeadlessChrome = /\bHeadlessChrome\//.test(navigator.userAgent)
Vue.config.devtools = !isHeadlessChrome
Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

but is there any way to run it before ALL unit tests ?

Answer (score 1):

In the karma.conf.js file , preprocessors are indicated :

preprocessors: {
      './index.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

so I acn insert the piece of code inside test/unit/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const isHeadlessChrome = /\bHeadlessChrome\//.test(navigator.userAgent)
Vue.config.devtools = !isHeadlessChrome
Vue.config.productionTip = false
```